# How to group two rows together in rdlc?

Tags: rdlc

Top table in image is from generated pdf. I want last 4 rows to be grouped as two row groups like the top row group which is showing northing, easting and area. Effectively the line between header row and value row should not be there.

But for some reason when i add rows, its not happening the way i expected. How should this be done ?

For better understanding i have also added snapshot showing the visual cues for the tablix.

[image]

Comment: Remove the bottom border of the rows you wish to "group", exactly like you did for the top 2 rows.

Comment: Thanks for your tip. It works. I had not done for the top 2 rows and it was done by someone else. Next rows were added by me and hence didnt know. I was under the impression that the lines between rows belongs to table. But later realized it is the textbox's border which is shown. I removed borders for each cell according to my need and it works now.